# How to get the head of a linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list

Say we have a linkedList

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list.add(3);
list.add(5);
list.add(6);
```

How can we access the head of the linkedlist?
The function getFirst() is not what I need here, since it only returns the first element 3 rather than the first node. How can I get the first node of the list?
The first node in my example is a node with value 3, pointing to 5.

Comment: `it only returns the first element 3 rather than the first node` ... `The first node in my example is a node with value 3` ... isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: The `LinkedList` type does not expose its internal implementation.

Comment: Hello Tim, What I mean is that I need a ListNode with a value of 3, instead of an Integer 3.

Comment: @user226629, unfortunately `java.util.LinkedList` don't expose any _Node_. You will only get `Element`s (in your case `Integer`) from the list.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the actual Node with the data, you can implement your own LinkedList class with a nested Node class, and return it in there. You do not have access to the "Node" that the java.util class uses in its implementation.

**Edit:** In case you would like to see in code what I am saying, consider the following code. Although it is not complete in any manner, I typed it out to demonstrate that you cannot simply make your own Node class and assign the java.util.LinkedList node to it, because you won't have access to the Node they use in their implementation. Instead, do something like the following:

```
public class MyList {
    private Node head;

    public Node getHeadNode() {
        return this.head;
    }
    public class Node {
        private int data;
        private Node next;
        //constructor
        public Node(int data) { this.data = data; this.next = null; }
    }
}
```